# Convert MDX query result into relational format

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx

I have a SQL stored proc that uses a linked server and Openquery to execute a MDX query.  The result returned from the MDX query is in the format of:

```
Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3 | Month 4

12        5         4         7
```

where the columns are dynamic i.e. I never know how many months will be in the output.

How can I transpose the output into a relational format e.g.

Two columns.

```
Col 1 | Col 2
-----   -----
Month1  12
Month2  5
Month3  4
```

etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change your original MDX query from something like :

```
Select
 [Months].members on 0
from [MyCube]
```

to something like this one :

```
Select
 [Measures].defaultmember on 0,
 [Months].members on 1
from [MyCube]
```

Comment: Yep I worked it out about an hour ago.  I'm new to MDX syntax.  Many thanks though.  I will give you the answer.